# Which solution is best for an Android music manager app?

Tags: java, android, file, android-file

I want to create a media manager app for android but I am unsure of how to access the information that I need. I want the app to do things like edit ID3 tags, find songs by the same artist and place them in a folder, and other media management tasks. What is the best way to access the media files - MediaStore? Storage Access Framework? Java.io.file?

The Android developer guide mentions that MediaStore is the preferred way to access media, but it is limited to specific directories, which is not what I want. For my purposes, it seems like an extra level of abstraction that is unnecessary if I am going to be accessing the files themselves anyway.

> In particular, if your app wants to access a file within the MediaStore.Downloads collection that your app didn't create, you must use the Storage Access Framework. To learn more about how to use this framework, see the guide on how to access documents and other files.

This excerpt from [the Android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#storage-permission) suggests using the Storage Access Framework, but as I understand it, this framework is limited to [a small set of use cases](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#use-cases). In particular, I think that asking the user for access to each directory via intents would make for a bad experience.

So the remaining option is to use the File class, and this seems to be the option recommended for use by file explorers. But it is not mentioned anywhere in the guide, which leads me to believe that its use is not recommended by the Android team. Is this true? Which option is right for my use case?

Comment: Hey, you think too much, free app here to see: https://github.com/naman14/Timber

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am not looking for a music player app. I want to make a small app that manages music. I don't think that looking through a large codebase for something that's barely related is a good way to learn.

Comment: so you can search on google, so many good tutorial for you.I have made an music app before, and there are a ton of tutorials on stackoverfollow, all your worries are answered, don't worry, start working.